# How do you classify the singularities of a complex function by just looking at the equation?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am given the function $f(z) = \frac{(\sin{z}) \sqrt{z^2-1}}{(z-2)^2z}e^{1/(z-3)}$. My professor suggested that we can do this without checking the Laurent Series at each singularity.

My reasoning as of now is:

Right off the bat we know that $z = \pm 1$ are branch points because they are under the square root.

I am fairly certain the singularity at $z=0$ is a simple pole like it would be in any function of the form $g(z) = c/z$.

The singularity at $z=3$ should be essential just as $z=0$ is essential for $e^{1/z}$.

At $z=2$ we have the behavior of $1/(z-2)^2$ which would be a pole of order 2.

As $z\rightarrow \infty$ it seems like $f(z)\rightarrow 0$.

Is this method of eyeballing the function giving me the right answers or am I completely wrong in looking at each singularity separately?

Comment: The only thing you have to be careful is whether or not the "candidate poles" are indeed poles, since they may cancel with something in the numerator. For instance, $\sin(z)/z$ does not have a pole at $z=0$. Other than that, your eyeballing gave you the right idea.

Comment: also $\sin(z)$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$

Comment: To add to the comment from @bartgol , note that if a square root term appears as the argument of an even function, it has no branch point.  For example, $\cos (\sqrt{z^2-1})$ does not have branch points at $z=\pm 1$. So, one needs to be careful and circumspect in "eye-balling" things.  And +1 for your question!